# Menu above logo when resize

Tags: html, css, header, resize

I have been doing the frontend of a website. However i'm with problems in the header area. When i resize the window my menu stays above the logo. I don't want this. Any suggestion? I don't know what to do to solve this problem. I'm using bootstrap.

Heres the site
http://franciscowanzeller.com/rede/

Thanks,

Comment: Your logo is positioned using `absolute`, update that when the menu goes above the logo using media queries.

Answer (score 1):

to resize the picture in the `IMG` tag like this

```
img {
max-width:100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change css-

```
.header {
    background: url("../images/header_3.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 20em;
    position:relative
}

 .logo {
    left: 13em;
    /*margin-left: 15em;*/
    position: absolute;
}
```

and fix the width according your container.